# Start XBMC Automatically for specific user

Tags: login, users, autostart, xbmc

This is my first post on Ask Ubuntu and I have only been using Ubuntu as an OS for a week or so. So far, loving is :D

But onto the problem. Basically I am wanting to set up a couple of user accounts on my laptop, 1 for XBMC and the other for using Ubuntu normally. 
I am using Ubuntu Saucy Salamander.

So for example if I have 2 users, here is what I want them to do:
XBMC - boot directly into XBMC upon login
USER - run Ubuntu as normal.

I'm not sure if this is possible but I imagine it would be.

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this (start-up scripts in a real desktop, separate X sessions) but I think the best for the method you're suggesting is adding a XBMC session and using that from your secondary user.

**Note:** some distributions of XBMC include the following already. All you might need to do is change session at the login screen. Click the down button next to the username and pick XBMC.

If you don't have an XMBC option already, add one by running `sudoedit /usr/share/xsessions/XBMC.desktop` and fill it with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XBMC
Comment=This session will start XBMC Media Center
Exec=xbmc-standalone
TryExec=xbmc-standalone
Type=Application
```

You might need to run `sudo restart lightdm` (this will kill all running desktops and graphical apps) but then you should be able to pick an XBMC option at the login screen.

And if that doesn't work, check `xbmc-standalone` exists with `which xbmc-standalone`. Some distributions of XBMC don't ship a separate -standalone variant so just change the command to `xbmc`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will give this a try as soon as possible. fingers crossed.